# How do I disable instant syntax error highlighting in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I got Visual Studio 2015 Professional several months ago.  One thing that has irked me ever since is how the syntax error checking fires off immediately after typing, whereas in 2013 the error checks only happened after you have moved away from your current line of code.

This is kind of difficult to explain what I mean.  Essentially, if I type a quotation mark every single bit of code below that point immediately switches to string and everything highlights as errors.  Halfway through creating a variable, Visual Studio is highlighting it saying it is an unused variable.

Is there a way to turn this feature off?  I have been poring over every options menu I can find, disabling options one by one and I cannot find a solution.  I have also googled ad nauseum and searched for a solution but it is either difficult to search for or nobody else minds.  I find this feature highly annoying because the editor is screaming at me before I have even progressed halfway through a line of code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I've never even noticed that because whenever I type a quotation mark, VS inserts the ending quotation mark for me.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than referring another website, I would suggest simple solution below:

```
Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> General >> Show error squiggles
```

**uncheck** "Show error squiggles" checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe this link can help you.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/05/01/how-to-turn-off-automatic-intellisense/

Also You can change colors for that error highlights (cheat your mind),
look for the error color and choose one equal to the back color of the editor.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh923906.aspx

I hope this can help you