# Disable Visual Studio 2015 VB Intellisense highlight syntax error as I type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, syntax-error, intellisense

Earlier versions of Visual Studio (I have used 2013, 2010, 2005) would let you finish typing your line before (rudely!) telling you that you have a syntax error. I feel 2015 version jumps the gun and it is very distracting and annoying. Is there a way to "fix" this "feature" in option settings?

[image: View Example]

Comment: Try this "fix". Do both of the double quotes for the string first, then left arrow back inside and then enter your string.

Comment: @Mathemats. Doesn't 2015 already have this as an options to automatically put your cursor between "" and () when you type the starting character?

Comment: Double quotes does prevent the rest of code from being highlighted as error, however it in itself is a nuisance to do every time. :(

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712935/how-do-i-disable-instant-syntax-error-highlighting-in-visual-studio-2015?rq=1

Comment: Please figure this out, right now i'm reverting to an older VS version - constant red underlining as i type break my concentration every time.